# Помогите понять почему не ставится фон

Tags: html, css

Когда я вставляю блок `<ul>` в блок `<div>` на месте списка фон не становится красным. Если же блок `<ul>` убрать, то красный фон появляется.
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background-color: black;
}
#TopMenu {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 2em;
}
#TopMenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  word-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_title">Добро пожаловать на портал
  <br/>об удивительном мире Средиземья</div>
<div id="headImg"></div>
<div id="TopMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="page.html">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Тематика</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Об авторе</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html"> Бестиарий</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Краткая история мира</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы используете `background-color` для всех элементов по умолчанию:

```
* {
   ...
   ...
   background-color: black; /*--- будет всем элементам страницы ставить черный фон по умолчанию ---* /
  }
```

**Решение:** убрать `background-color: black;` по умолчанию для всех элементов, прописать `background-color: black;` для `body`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  
}
body{
  background-color: black;
}
#TopMenu {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 2em;
}
#TopMenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  word-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_title">Добро пожаловать на портал
  <br/>об удивительном мире Средиземья</div>
<div id="headImg"></div>
<div id="TopMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="page.html">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Тематика</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Об авторе</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html"> Бестиарий</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Краткая история мира</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Проблема решена, но почему * работает именно так? Если посмотреть в опере код элемента, то цвет остается красным.

Comment: @Юрий потому, что `*` - это [универсальный селектор, который соответствует любому элементу веб-страницы](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/universalnyy-selektor). В опере это правило [так же работает](http://prntscr.com/a36abp) как и в других браузерах.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение!

Comment: Рады были помочь) Однако пожалуйста, не пишите комментарии в виде "спасибо". Комментарии служат для разъяснения подробностей вопроса/ответа. Когда у Вас будет достаточно [привилегий](//ru.stackoverflow.com/privileges), Вы сможете голосовать за понравившийся Вам вопрос/ответ, что на сайте Stack Overflow на русском является способом сказать спасибо.